# Using function as parameter for if statement in go

Tags: go

I'm trying to get the following to work:

```
func ArticlesHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  ...
  if(ValidTokenProvided(w,r)){
    ...
  }
  ...
}
func ValidTokenProvided(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  ...
  return false
}
```

How can I pass a function as a parameter? or if I can't, what is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: There is an opening parenthesis after the `if` keyword. It is never closed and will cause a syntax error. And it is not really necessary either.

Comment: Oops, made that mistake writing the example, my code is good. My answer is correct, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ValidTokenProvided was a void method.. Made it bool:

```
func ValidTokenProvided(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) bool {
...
```